# D3, nested appends, and data flow

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm in the process of finally learning D3, and I stumbled upon a problem that I haven't been able to find an answer to. I'm not certain if my question is because I'm not thinking idiomatically with the library, or if it is because of a procedure that I am currently unaware of. I should also mention that I've only started doing web-related things in June, so I'm fairly new to javascript.

Say that we're building a tool that gives a user a list of foods with respective images. And lets add on the additional constraint that each list item needs to be labeled by a unique ID so that it can be linked to another view. My first intuition to solve this is to create a list of `<div>`'s each with their own ID, where each `div` has its own `<p>` and `<img>`. The resulting HTML would look something like:

```xml
<div id="chocolate">
  <p>Chocolate Cookie</p>
  <img src="chocolate.jpg" />
</div>
<div id="sugar">
  <p>Sugar Cookie</p>
  <img src="sugar.jpg" />
</div>
```

The data for this tool is in a JSON array, where an individual JSON looks like:

```
{ "label": "sugar", "text": "Sugar Cookie", "img": "sugar.jpg" }
```

Is there a way to do generate the HTML in one fell swoop? Starting with a base case of adding a div, the code might look something like:

```
d3.select(containerId).selectAll('div')                                                          
   .data(food)
   .enter().append('div')
   .attr('id', function(d) { return d.label; });
```

Now, what about adding a `<div>` with a `<p>` in it? My original thought was to do something like:

```
d3.select(containerId).selectAll('div')                                                          
   .data(food)
   .enter().append('div')
   .attr('id', function(d) { return d.label; })
       .append('p').text('somethingHere');
```

But, I see two problems with this: (1) how do you get the data from the `div` element, and (2) how can you append multiple children to the same parent in one declarative chain? I can't think of a way to make the third step where I would append on the `img`.

I found mention of nested selection on another post, which pointed to http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/. But is nested selection, and therefore breaking apart the appends into three chunks, appropriate/idiomatic for this situation? Or is there actually a well-constructed way to form this structure in one chain of declarations? It seems like there might be a way with subselections mentioned on https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections, but I'm not familiar enough with the language to test that hypothesis.

From a conceptual level, these three objects (`div`, `p`, and `img`) are treated more like one group rather than separate entities, and it would be nice if the code reflected that as well.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You cannot add multiple child elements within one chained command. You will need to save the parent selection in a variable. This should do what you want:

```
var data = [{ "label": "chocolate", "text": "Chocolate Cookie", "img": "chocolate.jpg" },
        { "label": "sugar", "text": "Sugar Cookie", "img": "sugar.jpg" }];

var diventer = d3.select("body").selectAll("div")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("div")
    .attr("id", function(d) { return d.label; });

diventer.append("p")
    .text(function(d) { return d.text; });

diventer.append("img")
    .attr("src", function(d) { return d.img; });​
```

See working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UNjuP/

You were wondering how a child element like `p` or `img`, gets access to the data that is bound to its parent. The data is inherited automatically from the parent when you append a new element. This means that the p and img elements will have the same data bound to them as the parent div.

This data propagation is not unique for the `append` method. It happens with the following `selection` methods: [`append`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-append), [`insert`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-insert), and [`select`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-select).

For example, for selection.append:

> ## selection.append(name)
>
> Appends a new element with the specified name as the last child of
>   each element in the current selection. Returns a new selection
>   containing the appended elements. Each new element inherits the data
>   of the current elements, if any, in the same manner as select for
>   subselections. The name must be specified as a constant, though in the
>   future we might allow appending of existing elements or a function to
>   generate the name dynamically.

Feel free to ask about the details if something is not clear.

---

EDIT

You can add multiple child elements without storing the selection in a variable by using the `selection.each` method. You can then also directly access the data from the parent:

```
var data = [{ "label": "chocolate", "text": "Chocolate Cookie", "img": "chocolate.jpg" },
        { "label": "sugar", "text": "Sugar Cookie", "img": "sugar.jpg" }];

d3.select("body").selectAll("div")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("div")
    .attr("id", function(d) { return d.label; })
    .each(function(d) {
        d3.select(this).append("p")
          .text(d.text);
        d3.select(this).append("img")
          .attr("src", d.img);
    });
```

Comment: Fantastic! I hadn't realized that children nodes had the same data scope. Thanks for the clarification :)

Comment: If you use `selection.each` to insert grouped (or nested) nodes, remember to also use `selection.each` for the update step (and maybe for the exit step as well).

Comment: Note: Change of data of parent does not get automatically reflected in appended child.

Comment: It does when the datum is an Object. Since parent and child have a reference to the same Object, making a change to the Object will automatically be reflected in parent and child.

Answer (score 28):

Again, not substantively different, but my preferred method would be to use 'call'

```
var data = [{ "label": "chocolate", "text": "Chocolate Cookie", "img": "chocolate.jpg" },
        { "label": "sugar", "text": "Sugar Cookie", "img": "sugar.jpg" }];

d3.select("body").selectAll("div")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("div")
    .attr("id", function(d) { return d.label; })
  .call(function(parent){
    parent.append('p').text(function(d){ return d.text; });
    parent.append('img').attr("src", function(d) { return d.img; });​
  });
```

you don't need to store any variables and you can factor out the called function if you want to use a similar structure elsewhere.

Comment: love it! this made it super easy for me to handle updating deeply nested objects

Comment: this one fits my needs much better than the one above, since I have no data and I just want to re-use a parent inside, without using an outside variable, thank you!

Comment: As for me, this is a best practice for creating nested elements. Thank you so much!

Comment: @NgoQuangDuong that's very kind, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

This isn't fundamentally different from [nautat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13204545/1281433), but I think that the code can be made a bit cleaner by saving the *update* selection rather than the *enter* selection, and getting the *enter* selection from it for the one operation that needs it (adding the surrounding div).

When you insert or append an element into the **enter()** selection, it's added to the update selection that you can work with afterward.  This means that you can join the data, then add a div with the enter selection, and then when you append with the update selection, you'll be appending *within* the divs that you added in the enter selection:

```js
var cookies = [
  { "label": "sugar", "text": "Sugar Cookie", "img": "sugar.jpg" },
  { "label": "chocolate", "text": "Chocolate Cookie", "img": "chocolate.jpg" }];

var cookie = d3.select("#cookie-jar").selectAll().data(cookies);
cookie.enter().append("div");
cookie.append("p").text(function(d){ return d.text });
cookie.append("img").attr("src",function(d){ return d.img });
```

```css
#cookie-jar div { border: solid 1px black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="cookie-jar"></div>
```