# d3.js nested selections

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to create `<g>` elements foreach datapoint I have and add in a couple different `<text>` elements to each `<g>` element based on the current datapoint.  I've tried something like:

```
var g = vis.selectAll("g").data(dd,function(d){ return d.data.name+d.x+d.y+d.s; });

    var gs = g.enter().append("g");         
        g.exit().remove();

    var t = gs.selectAll("text").data(function(d) { console.log(d); return d; });
    t.enter().append("text").attr("x",function(d){ return d.x+d.s/2; })
        .attr("y",function(d){ return d.y+d.s/4; })
        .attr("font-family","Verdana")
        .attr("font-size","9")          
        .attr("text-anchor","middle")
        .text(function(d){ return d.data.name; });      

    t.attr("x",function(d){ return d.x+d.s/2; })
        .attr("y",function(d){ return d.y+d.s/4; })
        .attr("font-family","Verdana")
        .attr("font-size","9")          
        .attr("text-anchor","middle")
        .text(function(d){ return d.data.name; });      

    t.exit().remove();
```

But all I get are a set of empty `<g>` elements.  Am I doing something obviously wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nested selections assume some kind of nested data, e.g. a matrix. Your individual data elements are not arrays, so the second call to `.data()` doesn't do anything. Have a look at the [tutorial on nested selections](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/) for more details.

It's not clear to me why you want nested selections in your case. You're adding a `text` element that displays the name for a data point, so you shouldn't need the second (nested) selection. The easiest way to fix it (at least syntactically) however should be to change each element of `dd` into a single-element array.

Comment: Well, I simplified my problem a little bit.  I want to add a bunch of things to each group (a few text elements, a rectangle, etc).  I've already implemented it using a flat structure where I manually place each element, but that makes transitions not in sync.  I thought the nested structure made sense since I essentially wanted each datapoint to be represented by a group of items.  What would you suggest for this type of problem?

Comment: This doesn't sound like nested selections would be useful -- they definitely won't help with your out of sync transitions. You could try setting custom parameters for your transitions or even writing a custom transition depending on what exactly you want to do. See [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions).

Comment: Putting aside the nested stuff, how can i attach multiple elements to a <g> element where the <g> elements are created by some array of datapoints (i.e., the <g> elements enter/exit/update and so do the inner elements into the <g>)

Comment: You can use the 'each' method on the g elements enter selection and then within the each function use d3.select(this).append(el1); d3.select(this).append(el2); to append multiple elements to each g element. See for example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13204545/760156