# Dynamically adjust bubble radius of counties?

Tags: d3.js

Following the County Bubbles example, it's easy to add a bubble for each county. This is how it is added in the example:

```
svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "bubble")
    .selectAll("circle")
      .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.counties).features
        .sort(function(a, b) { return b.properties.population - a.properties.population;     }))
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + path.centroid(d) + ")"; })
      .attr("r", function(d) { return radius(d.properties.population); })
    .append("title")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.properties.name
            + "\nPopulation " + formatNumber(d.properties.population);
      });
```

However, rather than using a variable from the json file (population), I need to update the radii according to a variable which dynamically changes (so I cannot put it in the json file beforehand as was done in the example). I call updateRadii() when a county is clicked, which needs access to the FIPS.

```
var currFIPS,
    flowByFIPS;

var g = svg.append("g");

queue()
    .defer(d3.json, "us.json")
    .defer(d3.csv, "census.csv", function(d) {
        return {
            work: +d.workplace,
            home: +d.residence,
            flow: +d.flow
        }
    })
    .await(ready);

function ready(error, us, commute) {
    // Counties
    g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "counties")
      .selectAll("path")
        .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.counties).features)
      .enter().append("path")
        .attr("d", path)
        .on("click", function(d) {
            // Get FIPS of selected county
            currFIPS = d.id;

            // Filter on selected county (i.e., grab
            // people who work in the selected county)
            var data = commute.filter(function(d) { 
                return d.work == currFIPS;
            });

            // Create d3.map for where these people live
            flowByFIPS = d3.map(data, function(d) { 
                return d.home;
            });

            // Update radii at "home" counties to reflect flow
            updateRadii();
        });

    // Bubbles
    g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "counties")
      .selectAll("circle")
        .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.counties).features)
      .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("id", function(d) { return d.id; })
        .attr("transform", function(d) { 
            return "translate(" + path.centroid(d) + ")"; 
        })
        .attr("r", 0);  // invisible before a county is clicked
}

function updateRadii() {
    svg.selectAll(".counties circle")
        .transition()
        .duration(300)
        .attr("r", function(d) { 
            return flowByFIPS.get(d.id).flow 
        });
}
```

According to the error code, I believe that the circles do not have an id (FIPS code) attached. How do I get them to have an id? (I tried nesting the circle with the path using `.each` as explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13204545/2755084), but could not get it working.)

Note that the above code works for updating fill on paths (rather than circles). For example, sub `updateRadii();` for `updateFill();` with the function as:

```
function updateFill() {
    svg.selectAll(".counties path")
        .transition()
        .duration(300)
        .attr("fill", function(d) { 
            return flowByFIPS.get(d.id).color;  // e.g., "#444"
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be an obvious solution. I forgot to check for the cases where a flow doesn't exist. The code above works if `updateRadii()` is changed to:

```
function updateRadii() {
    svg.selectAll(".counties circle")
        .transition()
        .duration(300)
        .attr("r", function(d) {
            if (currFIPS == d.id) {
                return 0;
            }

            var county = flowByFIPS.get(d.id);

            if (typeof county === "undefined") {
                return 0;
            } else {
                return county.flow; 
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you don't supply d3 with data in the update function. I will recommend you update the data loaded from the file on the clicks, and from there you update the svg.

```
var update = function() {
  g.selectAll(".country")
  .data(data)
  .attr("r", function(d) { return d.properties.flow_pct });
};

var data = topojson.feature(us, us.objects.counties).features;
data.forEach(function(x) { x.properties.flow_pct = /* calc the value */; })

g.append("g")
.attr("class", "counties")
.selectAll(".country")
.data(data)
.enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("class", "country")
  .attr("transform", function(d) { 
    return "translate(" + path.centroid(d) + ")"; 
  })
  .on("click", function(d) {

    // more code
    data.forEach(function(x) { x.properties.flow_pct = /* calc the NEW value */; })

    update();
  });

update();
```

I've tried to use as much as the same code as before, but still trying to straiten it a bit out. The flow is now more d3-like, since the update function works on the changed data.

Another plus which this approach is both first render and future updates use the same logic for finding the radius.

Comment: Thanks for taking a crack at it. I think the way this is written `data` is still just the json file, which doesn't have the `flow_pct` in it. I'll update the question to make things more clear.

Comment: Actually, when the json is parsed it becomes just another javascript object. `data.forEach(function(x) { x.properties.flow_pct = /* calc the value */; })` will enrich the data with what you like `flow_pct` to be.

Comment: Ah okay. `flow_pct` is filtered on a click though. I added more details about. Maybe my problem will be more clear. (Note that I simplifed `flow_pct` to just `flow` for the example.)