# Return compiled text in d3's text() or html() method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I have the following d3 code:

```
grouping.append('foreignObject').html(function (d) {
  var string = '<p>hello, {{ "there" }} <some-directive></some-directive></p>';
  string = $compile(string)(scope);
  return string;
});
```

The problem is that at the end, `string` is an actual HTML object, but d3 needs it to be just a string. I have tried converting it to text using the [XMLSerializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XMLSerializer), but that reverted it back to the original `string`, which isn't compiled.

Basically, I need to compile some elements and return them as a string to the d3 method. How can I do this?

Comment: Since you already have the actual HTML object, can you just [keep appending](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13203897/d3-nested-appends-and-data-flow)?

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
$("<i>").html("<b>Sample</b> text").text() // returns "Sample text"
```

Comment: No, I need the whole html code as a string. I realize the way I phrased the question may have been confusing, so I updated it.